# disallow download option

Tags: permissions, 2016

I have users with **Read permission** whose "Can view pages and list items and download documents." Is it possible to disallow download option for read permission, without IRM?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the users with 'View Only' permissions.

"View pages, items, and documents. Any document that has a server-side file handler can be viewed in the browser **but not downloaded**. File types that do not have a server-side file handler (cannot be opened in the browser), such as video files, .pdf files, and .png files, can still be downloaded."

More information about the permissions [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)